# Different versions of OpenGL for iGPU and dGPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel, opengl

I have a laptop with an integrated GPU Intel HD Graphics 5500 and an NVIDIA GeForce 840M, and I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to install the CUDA toolkit 7.5 and I need OpenGL 4.3 support.

If I enable installation of OpenGL drivers with the toolkit, I get the login-loop problem after reboot. If I disable OpenGL with the `--no-opengl-libs` option of the toolkit installation on the other hand, it works fine and I can login without problems.

The problem as described by the Installation Guide is this:

> If the GPU used for display is not an NVIDIA GPU, the NVIDIA openGL libraries should not be installed. Otherwise, the openGL libraries used by the graphics driver of the non-NVIDIA GPU will be overwritten and the GUI will not work.

So the iGPU OpenGL drivers are replaced with the dGPU drivers, which makes the Ubuntu GUI crash on login.

Running `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` tells me that the OpenGL version is 3.0, since that's what my current Intel HD Graphics 5500 driver supports:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units) though Intel HD Graphics 5500 supports Opengl 4.3 on linux, which is exactly what I need.

**Is it possible to upgrade the Intel drivers to support OpenGL 4.3 on my laptop ?** The Intel drivers are installed automatically, so I am unsure how I could upgrade them.

- If that doesn't work, can I have two different versions of OpenGL installed, so that the NVIDIA GPU uses its newest version >= 4.3 and that the Intel integrated GPU uses its normal version 3.0 for the GUI?

I cannot use the NVIDIA GPU for the GUI (if that's even possible) since I need it to run CUDA.